# Azure Application Gateway Not allowing Client Certificates

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have Azure API Management, configured internally and exposed to the public through Azure application Gateway.  My API is secured for client certificates, it working perfectly when I test it internally. When I test it externally, I am getting an invalid certificate error.  Does Azure Application Gateway block client certificates? How to allow them?

Answer (score 1):

An answer from Microsoft:

> We do have option for mutual authentication on Application Gateway
> which can allow the mutual authentication between *client* and
> *Application Gateway*:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/mutual-authentication-overview
>
> However this is still in preview version, which is not included in
> SLA. As the mutual authentication between *AppGW* and the *APIM* we
> double confirmed with the backend engineers, unfortunately the answer
> is no we do not support such a function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is not yet possible with Application Gateway: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/9379902-allow-mutual-ssl-auth-on-application-gateway

Comment: Is this now available?